# SQL Server performance - inserts

Tags: sql-server

I have a .NET application that inserts data in a SQL Server database, and the load in SQL Server for inserting new data when application load is large is quite high.

From time to time I get in the SQL Server logs:

> Error occured during bulk operation database. Operation had to be rolled back. Transaction was deadlocked on lock. Duplicate key was ignored

What does it mean especially that: *Duplicate key was ignored* ? I have logs where the duplicate key part is not present.

Is there a general solution for this kind of problems ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Duplicate key was ignored` is a warning/informational message that occurs when the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option is on for an index and there is an attempt to insert a duplicate value.

It is not an error in itself. It seems that if a subsequent error does actually occur that the process is just writing all messages from that stream to the log including those that do not actually relate to any error.

I've seen similar behaviour with SQL Server Agent job histories.

Comment: I had indeed a table where IGNORE_DUP_KEY was specified. So that seems to explain that. I wonder if this has anything to do with "Transaction was deadlocked on lock" or if I can do anything to improve things..

Comment: @Ghita - No it won't have anything to do with the deadlock. For troubleshooting the deadlock you are best off capturing the deadlock graph.

Comment: how can I capture that ? Any documentation ? Tnx

Comment: See http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/